# Android firebase token refresh failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Android firebase token refresh.

If any new token generated from firebase, it will call the onTokenRefresh and service will update the token to server.

1. Is there any way we check firebase directly from server to get the new tokens generated for clients with old tokens ?
2. If the mobile switched off for sometime and fire base tried to send the refresh token but it failed.
   How fire base will send the token in that case. will it keep try until it send the new token to device ?

Thanks

Comment: You can call **FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();** to get the latest token from Firebase and then compare it with your existing one and if found changed then you can update it on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the mobile switched off for sometime and fire base tried to send the refresh token but it failed. How fire base will send the token in that case. will it keep try until it send the new token to device ?

The Firebase servers don't **send** fresh tokens to devices. Instead, the Firebase SDK inside the device/app requests a new token when it detects that this is required. So this will only happen when the device is turned on.